# Identifying the numbers of AR or MA terms in matlab

Tags: r, matlab

How do I identify the order of ARMA model for given time series in matlab. In R, there is a function `ar`, `auto.arima` that searches for the optimal number of lags for AR and MA models. But I haven't been able to find a similar function in matlab. The `AR` function in matlab estimates parameters for a 'specified' number of lags. Any ideas?

Secondly, is there a function similar to `arima.sim` in matlab to simulate arima processes?

Comment: You could look at the R code and copy it's behavior in matlab

Comment: haha yes. But it takes time to develop and test code. I was looking for something that already exists out there as it is quite common.

Comment: well its not trivial to write these functions....

Answer (score 0):

I think that, if you want to do it using Mathworks products, this would be part of the [Statistical Signal Processing](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/signal/ug/f12-708.html) which is provided by the Signal Processing toolbox.

Comment: I was looking at that package and could not find these specific functions.

Comment: if you could point me to it if you know, that would be helpful. thx

Comment: Have you read the bit of the MATLAB help I've linked to? Especially the "spectral analysis" bit?

Comment: Yes I glanced over it. It is computing discrete fourier transforms. My questions is related to ARMA processes.

Comment: DFTs are a fast way of calculating periodograms, which you can use to infer the ARMA coefficients.